# Adding / removing controls with same reference name

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am adding controls on a panel one after the other when the user clicks on a button.
The controls are displayed one after the other on the panel. When the panel is full e.g. ten,
the next control added has to replace the first control that was added, but first I need to remove the first control.... the problem is that all the controls that are being created have the same reference e.g. "pic", now when I use panel1.Controls.Remove(pic) it does not specify that the control at the first position needs to be removed!!

```
int index = 0;  

if (util.GetSize() != 10)
{
    ms.Controls.Add(musNote);
}
else
{   
    ms.Controls.Add(musNote); //this to replace first musNote added... but before I need to remove the musNote that in that position already (problem all of the are musNote!!
    index++;
    if (index == 10)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
}
musNote.ShowNote();
```

The above is not the entire code but should be enough to tackle the problem.. if any info. is needed please ask me np.  Tks in advance for the help.

Comment: I read it twice, cant understand what you're asking with this `now when I use panel1.Controls.Remove(pic) it does not specify that the control at the first position needs to be removed`

Comment: Example I can add only ten musicNotes on the panel due to the width. When the panel is full and the user add another music note, this music note has to replace the first one. How can I remove specifically the first one if all the musicNotes have the same reference name. Hope I am more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you just want to remove the first child use [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method</strike>

```
myPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
```

Don't use above code, it will leak in `Handle`, use Dispose as @Hans suggested in comments

```
myPanel.Controls[0].Dispose();//This takes care of destroying the window
```

Comment: That's a very nasty leak, never recommend that.  Use myPanel.Controls[0].Dispose() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Dispose then remove also required or not?

Comment: No, Dispose() also automatically removes it from the Controls collection.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, Updateed my answer. it is a shame that Control class doesn't implement a Finalizer to destroy it.

Comment: Of course it does :)  Ask a question about the "parking window" if you want to learn more.

Comment: Issue has been resolved in just few lines of code... I just did an if statement that checks if the container is full.. if not i just add the control if yes i remove control at index 0 and add the new note instead of it. Tks

Comment: @HansPassant I've raised a question about [ParkingWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585012/what-are-parking-windows-in-winforms) Take a look at it if you don't mind